# Split data and find average Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel file with a 1000 rows of data. I want to split the data in a way that I have 40 arrays of 25 rows each and get the average of the data. how do I do this?

Comment: Do you want to physically see the 40 arrays or just need the 40 averages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These solutions are Non-Volatile

Assuming the data is located in `A1:A1000`

***Solution 1***: Showing only the `Average` of the 40 sub ranges (see fig. 1)

**Array Number**: Enter this formula in `B2`, copy till `B41` then copy\paste the values

`=SUM(1,B1)`

**Averages**: Enter this formula in `C3` and copy till `C41`

`=AVERAGE(INDEX($A$1:$A$1000,($B2*25)-24):INDEX($A$1:$A$1000,($B2*25)))`

[image]

***Solution 2:*** Shown the 40 sub ranges and the averages (see fig. 2):

**Array Number:** Enter this formula in `B3`, copy till `B27` then copy\paste the values

`=SUM(1,B1)`

Enter this formula in `C2`, copy till `AP2` then copy\paste the values

`=SUM(1,B2)`

**Arrays:** Enter this formula in `C3`, copy till `C27` the copy till column `AP`

`=INDEX($A$1:$A$1000,(C$2*25)-25+$B3)`

**Averages:** Enter this formula in `C1` then copy till `AP1`

`=AVERAGE(C$2:C$27)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:

1. Your data is in column A, starting from the top
2. You want your output in columns D and later

I would propose the following:

1. You leave cell C1 blank
2. In cell D1, you enter the formula `= C1 +1`
3. In cell C2, you enter the formula `= C1 +1`
4. Now you can drag down column C untill you get to 25 rows and row 1 untill you get to 40 columns
5. In the matrix you just created, cell D2 is the first data point. In this cell, you enter the formula `= OFFSET( $A$1, 40 * ( D$1 - 1 ) + $C2 - 1, 0 )`, which you can now drag down and across.

The offset function takes the cell that is i rows below and j rows to the right of the first argument (in this case $A$1). we don't need any column offset, so the third argument is 0. The second argument looks at the column number of your matrix to see which sub-array it's looking at ("40 * ( D$1 - 1 )") and to the row number of your matrix to see which entry within the sub-array it should take ("$C2 - 1"). The "-1" is just because we started counting at 1 instead of 0.

For the averages, you can just use the `= AVERAGE()` function for each sub-array.

To make it a bit clearer, you can take [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOZ7m.png) as an example. The `= RANDBETWEEN()` function in column A was just for testing purposes.